# How to convert PythonRDD (of lines in JSONs) to DataFrame?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to read multiple JSONs to create a DataFrame.

I'm putting together multiple JSONs files into a PythonRDD, then when I try to convert to DataFrame it fails. Either I use the method `toDF()` or `sqlContext.createDataFrame()` I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Some of types cannot be determined by the first 100 rows, please try again with sampling
```

It is strange because using `sqlContext.read.json()` works fine.

Here is my code:

```
import json
from pyspark.sql import Row

def dict_to_row(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, dict) and len(obj.values())>0:
        d = {}
        for k in obj.keys():
            d[k] = dict_to_row(obj[k])
            return Row(**d)
    elif isinstance(obj, list):
        return [dict_to_row(o) for o in obj]
    else:
        return obj

def distributed_json_read(filename):
    jsons = open(filename,'r')
    json_list = jsons.readlines()
    for e in json_list:
        json_row = json.loads(e.rstrip())
        yield dict_to_row(json_row)

json_list = ['test1.json','test2.json']
parallel_keys = sc.parallelize(json_list)
data_rdd = parallel_keys.flatMap(distributed_json_read)
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data_rdd)
```

And here is an example of test1.json:

```
{
    "data": {
        "f": {
            "a": {
                "a1": 100,
                "a2": 1
            },
            "b": [
                {
                    "b1": {
                        "b11": 1,
                        "b12": null
                    },
                    "date1": "2016-02-05T01:58:04.000-0400",
                    "b2": {
                        "b21": null,
                        "b22": "9ca6d130fddb",
                        "b23": false
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "id": 1689
}
```

Someone has experience this error?

Actually my goal is to read multiple JSONs files which can have different schemas, but at the end build a DataFrame whose schema will be the union of the JSONs schemas. Similar to what you can achieve with sqlContext.read.json() if the parameter is a file with multiple JSONs inside.

Comment: I am slightly confused. Why do you create Rows instead of reading JSON directly?

Comment: Hi @zero323 my final goal is read JSONs from different S3 buckets. I want to read them in parallel, that's why I'm not able to use read.json() function

Answer (score 1):

I have written a custom json reader before for spark. I used either a sc.wholeTextFiles() or sc.binaryFiles() on the folder that contains the json files.

This will give you an rdd (k,v) of (file_url, wholeFile/BinaryFile)
then you can apply yout flat map on that rdd

rdd = sc.wholeTextFiles("super_folder_containing_jsons")

data_rdd = rdd.flatMap(distributed_json_read) 

df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data_rdd)

Comment: I'm not sure that your solution works, because if you use a function inside flatMap (for instance) you don't have access to sc (SparkContext).

Comment: yes, agreed, and you dont need to use sc in your distributed_json_read or in dict_to_row, with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

You either provide static schema(super set of all types) for the data frame or provide the code the first json with all fields which will help to have a default schema.

One issue when you dont have default schema and you give a json(with less fields), it might have issues later reading the new json files with new fields.

Comment: I known beforehand the global schema, but it seems that when Spark is trying to build the final RDD fails if 2 JSONs or more doesn't have the same schema.

Answer (score 0):

JSONs in Spark have to be one-liners, i.e. a single JSON file should be a single line.

```
scala> final case class Token(id: Int, body: String)
defined class Token

scala> val df = spark.createDataset(Seq(Token(0, "hello"), Token(1, "world")))
df: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[Token] = [id: int, body: string]

scala> df.show
+---+-----+
| id| body|
+---+-----+
|  0|hello|
|  1|world|
+---+-----+

scala> df.write.json("so.json")

// $ cat so.json/part-r-00003-469964b4-aaf8-4c7a-8f8a-d76c08e792ce.json
// {"id":0,"body":"hello"}
```

Comment: actually the JSONs are one-liner, I just put in pretty-print.